How moving the data to constant memory increases the Long Scoreboard Stall
I'm trying to implement a basic GEMM convolution algorithm in CUDA kernel. As much as I know, storing the constant datas in constant memory then broadcasting the threads is a optimization as long as threads in warp accesses the same element of constant memory as I did in my kernel. Execution time result proves that also. When I take a look at Warp State Statistics, I have seen "moving the convolution matrix to constant memory" reduces the Stall LG Throttle almost %50 as expected (half of the global memory accesses now being provided by constant memory). But in the other hand, it increases the Stall Long Scoreboard delay. Both constant and global memory versions have almost same IPC. But constant memory version has approximately %17 less instructions which means where speed up comes from. I have two questions :
1-How using constant memory reduces the total instruction count ?
2-Why constant memory usage creates Stall Long Scoreboard ?
These are the convolution kernels
__constant__ float CM_Filter[3][3] = {{1 / 16.0f, 2 / 16.0f, 1 / 16.0f},
                                       {2 / 16.0f, 4 / 16.0f, 2 / 16.0f},
                                       {1 / 16.0f, 2 / 16.0f, 1 / 16.0f}};
__device__ float GM_Filter[3][3] = {{1 / 16.0f, 2 / 16.0f, 1 / 16.0f},
                                     {2 / 16.0f, 4 / 16.0f, 2 / 16.0f},
                                     {1 / 16.0f, 2 / 16.0f, 1 / 16.0f}};

/*imtype is a float32*/
__global__ void GM_3x3(const imtype* __restrict__ input, imtype* __restrict__ output, const int rows, const int cols){
    int ty = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int tx = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    if ((tx > 0 && tx < rows - 1) && (ty > 0 && ty < cols - 1)) {
        output[tx * cols + ty] = (GM_Filter[0][0] * input[(tx - 1) * cols + ty - 1]
        + GM_Filter[0][1] * input[(tx - 1) * cols + ty]
        + GM_Filter[0][2] * input[(tx - 1) * cols + ty + 1]
        + GM_Filter[1][0] * input[tx * cols + ty - 1]
        + GM_Filter[1][1] * input[tx * cols + ty]
        + GM_Filter[1][2] * input[tx * cols + ty + 1]
        + GM_Filter[2][0] * input[(tx + 1) * cols + ty - 1]
        + GM_Filter[2][1] * input[(tx + 1) * cols + ty]
        + GM_Filter[2][2] * input[(tx + 1) * cols + ty + 1]);
    }
}

__global__ void CM_3x3(const imtype* __restrict__ input, imtype* __restrict__ output, const int rows, const int cols)
{
    int ty = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int tx = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    if ((tx > 0 && tx < rows - 1) && (ty > 0 && ty < cols - 1)) {
        output[tx * cols + ty] = (CM_Filter[0][0] * input[(tx - 1) * cols + ty - 1]
        + CM_Filter[0][1] * input[(tx - 1) * cols + ty]
        + CM_Filter[0][2] * input[(tx - 1) * cols + ty + 1]
        + CM_Filter[1][0] * input[tx * cols + ty - 1]
        + CM_Filter[1][1] * input[tx * cols + ty]
        + CM_Filter[1][2] * input[tx * cols + ty + 1]
        + CM_Filter[2][0] * input[(tx + 1) * cols + ty - 1]
        + CM_Filter[2][1] * input[(tx + 1) * cols + ty]
        + CM_Filter[2][2] * input[(tx + 1) * cols + ty + 1]);
    }
}


This is the warp states (blue bar represents constant memory version)

I have tried executing with uint8 and float32 data types to represent both images and filter matrix. Somehow representing with uint8 did not increase the Stall Long Scoreboard.

It is possible that one type of stall is hidden behind another and removing that one just reveals a stall that was there before. Imagine three instructions A B C where C depends on the result of A which causes stall type a and on the result of B with stall type b. When at first A has a higher latency than B, the stall type b wont appear at all. But after optimizing the latency of A, stall type b becomes visible even though the operation B has not changed at.

The reduction in instructions is easy enough to explain: The GPUs can take a constant memory address as an input into their arithmetic instructions. You can see it here in the SASS output on godbolt (look at the FFMA instructions with the c[…][…] input)

You can see in Nsight which instructions are actually responsible for the stalls so you can then understand what happens based on this and instruction dependency (the location of the stall is dependent of the actual target device and more specifically its architecture).

Long scoreboard basically means that the GPU has nothing to do while waiting for global memory. That isn't surprising since you do one computation (fused multiply-add) per memory access. Your particular GPU can probably do 35 FMAs for every float loaded from cache-cold GPU memory. Changing to uint8 doesn't do much because you still do 9 distinct memory load instructions and you just add one more conversion from int to float to the computation. It's probably better in cache performance but not enough.
